# how i can join two table on one column when one column have multiple code

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables :

**Table1**

```
    atypcode |  ABRNCHCOD   |   tarikh       |  codel
    1523     |   375        |    1397/06/31  |  375-500-652278-2,375-500-652278-3
    2179     |   344        |    1397/06/31  |  344-800-909999-1,344-800-909999-2
    2175     |   344        |    1397/06/31  |  344-500-1885840-1,344-500-1885840-2
    1523     |   375        |    1397/06/31  |  375-500-2852450-1,375-500-2852450-4
    1523     |   375        |    1397/06/31  |  375-500-651108-1,375-500-651108-2,375-500-651108-3
    4901     |   154        |    1397/06/31  |  154-305-260752-1,154-200-260752-1,154-800-13557-1
    2175     |   344        |    1397/06/31  |  344-500-1075560-1,344-500-1075560-2
    3312     |   344        |    1397/06/31  |  344-500-1885840-1,344-500-1885840-2
```

**Table2**

```
tarikh      |   codel               |    mande
1397/06/31  |   115-112-1882936-1   |    2798089.00
1397/06/31  |   115-112-1974907-1   |    72580645.00
1397/06/31  |   115-112-1974907-2   |    19052419.00
1397/06/31  |   115-112-2431483-1   |    0.00
1397/06/31  |   115-112-2472323-1   |    2643835.00
1397/06/31  |   115-112-2559539-1   |    1344235.00
1397/06/31  |   115-112-2807485-1   |    113614.00
1397/06/31  |   115-512-2556810-1   |    0.00
1397/06/31  |   115-512-2986840-1   |    130000000.00
1397/06/31  |   115-512-570205-1    |    0.00
```

and in table1 just one codel is exsist in table2
how i can search table2 in table1 based on codel without "in".

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the codes in the second table seem to match to the first table, and also, you should not be storing CSV data like this.  That being said, we can try the following trick:

```
SELECT t2.tarikh, t2.codel, t2.mande
FROM table2 t2
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1
              WHERE ',' + t1.codel + ',' LIKE '%,' + t2.codel + ',%');
```

To see how this works, consider the table 1 `codel` value:

```
375-500-651108-1,375-500-651108-2,375-500-651108-3
```

We first surround this value on both sides by comma to give:

```
,375-500-651108-1,375-500-651108-2,375-500-651108-3,
```

Then we just have to search a given `codel` value from table 2, also surrounded by commas, against this string, e.g. search for `,375-500-651108-1,`.

Comment: thanks, your solution it work but "EXISTS" like "in"  and to slow,i worked with +1 million record and this solution not good for my problem

Comment: You basically can't use an index for this query.  As I mentioned in my answer, the _best_ thing to do here, especially if you care about performance, would be to get each `codel` value onto a separate record.  With CSV, you are going to be stuck with poor performance.

Comment: one problem ,this code take '375-500-651108-1,375-500-651108-2,375-500-651108-3' is exist on other table,how i can get just one item when all item is exist?

Comment: I don't follow your question, but in any case, you should probably open a new question if you need help with something else.

Comment: ok thanks ,i create new qustion for my problem  and this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107615/how-i-can-get-just-one-item-is-exist-in-other-table-from-multiple-item-in-sql-se

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Try to use the string split function and use it in your join. Please split it in Select clause and use Alias.

```
STRING_SPLIT ( string , separator )
```