# How can I just get one item that exists in a table from a list of multiple items in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a question that relates to a question I have already had answered :

[link of my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106319/how-i-can-join-two-table-on-one-column-when-one-column-have-multiple-code)

now I have a problem, I want if exist all code in other table get just one code and removed other codes
like this sample

```
375-500-651108-1,375-500-651108-2,375-500-651108-3
```

3 code exist in other table and I want to get just one code

thanks

Comment: Hi,

Do you have a rule? Which of the three codes do you want? Or you select from Table2 and you remain with the code from table2?

Comment: @bilqashang . . . You should include all relevant information in this question.  It is fine to link to the other question, but each question should stand on its own.